# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is the Manifest File.
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem is adding permission. I also had this problem while doing a project.

You missed one permission. Find that one and give it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't supply your layout, but I had this same problem when I used the wrong Map API key in my MapView control.  Under Eclipse, you must generate the Key from "debug.keystore", **NOT** your distribution keystore.